# The concept for one-to-one mapping. Explain the mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

How to define a `One-to-One` relation between 2 classes ? I think I am going wrong somewhere,conceptually. I don't know what ,but it is.

Let us suppose there are two classes named `Country` and `PM` :

```
Country
  int c_id
  String name_c

PM
 int c_id
 String name_pm
```

Now for one country, there can only be one PM and PM can belong only to one country. How do I do this in my mapping file ?

I was trying this :

```
<class name="pojo.Country" table="country">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_c" />
      <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="name_pm" />
  </class>

  <class name="pojo.PM" table="pm">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_pm"  />
  </class>
```

But this effete mapping does nothing than to produce an exception during run time.It says the property `name_pm` cannot be found inside the `Country` class ! But does it search inside the `Country` class. It should rather search inside the `PM` class.

Also help me accomplish my `one-to-one` mapping between the 2 classes. I have been trying this for some time.

*Java Code:*

*Country*

```
    public class Country {
    private int c_id;
    private String name_c;

    public int getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }

    public void setC_id(int c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }

    public String getName_c() {
        return name_c;
    }

    public void setName_c(String name_c) {
        this.name_c = name_c;
    }

}
```

*PM*

```
    public class PM {
    private int c_id;
    private String name_pm;

    public int getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }

    public void setC_id(int c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }

    public String getName_pm() {
        return name_pm;
    }

    public void setName_pm(String name_pm) {
        this.name_pm = name_pm;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not a valid example because a country does not have to have a PM. In a one-to-one mapping **every** element of one set is associated with a unique element of the other.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the relation between your xml mapping and your Java code.

If you specify

```
  <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="name_pm" />
```

there needs to be a field named "name_pm" in your `Country` POJO.

You don't have such a field.

If your `Country` class has a field for the corresponding PM object, that field's name should be used here.

If neither class has a reference to the other, you need to add one.

What I would probably do with your code is to add a field to country and use its name in the mapping.

```
public class Country {
    private int c_id;
    private String name_c;
    private PM c_pm;

    public int getC_id() {
        return c_id;
    }

    public void setC_id(int c_id) {
        this.c_id = c_id;
    }

    public String getName_c() {
        return name_c;
    }

    public void setName_c(String name_c) {
        this.name_c = name_c;
    }

    public PM getC_pm() {
        return c_pm;
    }

    public void setC_pm(PM c_PM) {
        this.c_pm = c_pm;
    }

}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="pojo.Country" table="country">
      <id name="c_id">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="name_c" />
      <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="c_pm" />
</class>
```

*Disclaimer:*

I haven't tested any of this, and I'm not sure of exactly how the mapping should be done with a shared primary key.  If anyone else feels like providing a tested version, I'll happily upvote another answer or let this one turn "community wiki".

Comment: I didn't understand, except that I need `name_pm` to eliminate exception. Can you please explain, how `one-to-one` mapping is done

Comment: This might be a silly question..but really, how can I test/know if it is a `one-to-one` mapping ?

Answer (score 2):

If part of your question is also "...I think I am going wrong somewhere,conceptually... ", I'd like to provide some explanation.

First of all, `One-to-One` means, that the reference is between objects (instances). Other words, there must be reference from one object to other. Not only a common simple type (i.e. `String name_pm` or `String name_c`)

Both objects should reference each other:

```
public class PM {
    private Country country;  // reference to an instance of the PM
    ...
}

public class Country {
    private PM pm; // reference to an instance of the Country
    ...
}
```

On a *DB* level, it is a bit more trickier. Because references are based on `ID` columns and we do assure us, that these two `Country-PM` will always belong together, we have to reuse the `ID` value.

So, one object will play the role of the Master, e.g. Country and the second will assign its ID based on it. If we won't follow that pattern, we cannot be sure, that there will sooner or later arise some `many-to-one` or `many-to-many` relation.

And that's why the mapping usually looks like this

```
<class name="pojo.Country" table="country">
    <id name="c_id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="name_c" />
    <one-to-one class="pojo.PM" name="pm" cascade="save-update" />
</class>

<class name="pojo.PM" table="pm">
    <id name="pmid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="c_id" />
        <generator class="foreign">
           <param name="property">country</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="country" class="pojo.Country" constrained="true" />
</class>
```

*But one-to-one mapping is really very exceptional. I guess that mapping many-to-on on PM side (with country id reference in DB) could be more suitable. It is different approach at all, but...*

Please, try to see this nice article:

- [One-to-One example (XML Mapping)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/)
- [5.1.13. One-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone)

Comment: can we please discuss here @http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32215/discussion-between-radim-kohler-and-saplingpro

Comment: +1:  I believe it is possible to implement a unidirectional one-to-one, but birectional is usually better, and this is a good explanation.

Comment: @DonRoby Thanks so much. I started to write it down, when your answer was calling for more information ... it took me a bit later ;) +1 to you as well!

Comment: I am getting an exception `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id 
from null one-to-one property: country` as I try the mapping you gave in your answer.What is the reason for this ?

Comment: both directions must be assigned. I.e. `country.pm = pm; pm.country = country;`. This is a must, during creation. That will solve that exception