# Hibernate + MySQL + JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

1) I have 2 tables , user and user_profile with `OneToOne` Relationship,

user table:

> id,user_name,first_name,last_name - with ID has primary key,

user profile:

> id,name,user_id - with ID has primary key and user_id has foreign key
>   with user table

2) following are two JPA Entity objects

user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "user_name",unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public UserProfile userProfile;

    //with set/get methods
}
```

user profile:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="userProfile")
    private User user;

    // with set/get methods
}
```

When I am trying to insert into both the tables I see `user_id` column getting added into USER table with value and I don't see any value in the `user_id` column of USER_PROFILE table.

I am new to this MySQL could some one shed light how to fix this?

Comment: can you add you Sessionfactory class.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is backwards.  The @JoinColumn should be on user, not userProfile.

Answer (score 0):

The `one-to-one` relation does work a bit (well a lot) differently, then your code expects? I just tried to explain the same here: [The concept for one-to-one mapping. Explain the mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17251687/1679310). Please, read it.

The point is, that in `one-to-one` relation, there are some restrictions on your DB design. The relation is based on **both primary keys**. The `id` key column in `user` table has same values as the `id` column of the `user_profile`.

If you'd want to use `one-to-one` you'll need to

- change your table `user_profile`:
- It will have column `id`, the primary key not generated by identity.
- It does not have user_id any more.
- The `id` will be filled by NHibernate from `user` instance
- the mapping of `user_profile` must follow the one-to-one "slave" mapping

Small draft of the `user_profile` `id` mapping (id is generated by **"foreign"** not identity)

```
// Anottation
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", 
   parameters = @Parameter(name = "field", value = "user"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Take a look here for a nice example:  [One-to-One example (Annotation)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/). Here you'll find all answers and tips how to do that kind of mapping. *But also think if the one-to-one mapping is exactly what you need. Because it is a bit rare in real life...*

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
public UserProfile userProfile;
```

The annotations here mean that your USER table will contain a column USER_ID which will be a foreign key reference to the USER_PROFILE table. Is that what you were expecting? I think it should be renamed to USER_PROFILE_ID.

Here, you have not specified the column in the other table so you need to add:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private UserProfile userProfile;
```

In the UserProfile class, you can remove:

```
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;
```

The ID of the user should then appear in the USER column of the USER_PROFILE table.

Answer (score 0):

One to one  relationship is based on the Foreign Key concept where primary key of one table is used as a normal column to other table  in your code you are using to class

1. **User**
2. **UserProfile**

but  instead of using **@joinColumn** on id of **UserProfile** table you are using it on other column

so make is correct joining should be done on primary key not on other column.

Primary key should not be generated by identity.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned `@JoinColumn` is placed on the wrong table.  It should be included on the owning side of the relationship, which is the table containing the foreign key.  In your case that table is `UserProfile`.

**UserProfile**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    // with set/get methods
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "user_name",unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
    public UserProfile userProfile;

    //with set/get methods
}
```

See my [blog entry](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/5) about determining the owning side of an entity for more details.