# NHibernate unidirectional one-to-many relationship not saving foreign key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm new to NHibernate and I'm creating a simple scenario to test the framework functionalities.

I have to basic entities:

```
public class School : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

inheriting from a simple base class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

Than I map entities using FluentNhibernate this way:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(
        c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DataModel")))
   .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
       .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<BaseEntity>()
       .Where(t => t.Namespace == "MyApp.Models"))
       .IgnoreBase<BaseEntity>()
       .Override<User>(map =>
       {
           map.Table("Users");
           map.HasOne<School>(u => u.School).ForeignKey("SchoolId");
       })
       .Override<School>(map =>
       {
           map.Table("Schools");
       })
   ))
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

My test code is very simple:

```
using (var transaction = DbSession.BeginTransaction())
{
    Student u1 = DbSession.Get<Student>("user-id");
    School s1 = DbSession.Get<School>("school-id");

    u1.School = s1; // updating the associated school

    DbSession.SaveOrUpdate(u1);

    transaction.Commit(); // !!! the foreign key is not updated
}
```

Checkign the Students table, the row is not updated with the new school id.

So, what's wrong in my code? Is there something incorrect (or missing) in my mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Student` belonging to the `School` is a **`many-to-one`** relationship.

#### [5.1.11. many-to-one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

> An ordinary association to another persistent class is declared using a many-to-one element. The relational model is a many-to-one association. (It's really just an object reference.)

Its fluent version is **`.References()`**

#### [References / many-to-one](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#references--many-to-one)

> References is for creating many-to-one relationships between two entities, and is applied on the "many side." You're referencing a single other entity, so you use the References method. #HasMany / one-to-many is the "other side" of the References relationship, and gets applied on the "one side."
>
> Let's map a relationship between a book and its author.

```
public class Book
{
  public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
  public IList<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

> In domain terms, we have an Author which may be associated with any number of Books, and Books, each of which can be associated with a single Author.
>
> In database terms, we'd have a book table with a foreign key column referencing the primary key of an author table.
>
> To create the references relationship in your Book #ClassMap, add the following call in the BookMap constructor:

```
References(x => x.Author);
```

Other words, if we need the `many-to-one` relationship to be mapped with fluent, we cannot use **`.HasOne()`** but *.References()*

```
//map.HasOne<School>(u => u.School).ForeignKey("SchoolId");
map.References(u => u.School, "SchoolId");
```

To get full overview of the .References() API, read the second half of this article *(the first half is bout mapping by code, the second is comparison with fluent)*:

#### [mapping by code - Many-to-One](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) by Adam Bar

Note - what is the `.HasOne()` (the **`one-to-one`**) scenario issues could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17251687/1679310)

Comment: You're absolutely right! I was looking a the problem from the wrong point of view! Thank you.

Comment: Did that help a bit? Great ;) Enjoy mighty NHibernate, sir!